# Ising spin are bosonic?

Tags: condensed-matter, phase-transition, ising-model

I was going through the following paper [The 1D Ising model and the topological phase of the Kitaev chain](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.5262). They call ising spins to be bosonic. If I the quote the paper:

> Hard-core bosons realized through spin-flip operators acting on a Hilbert space with spin $s=\frac{1}{2}$.

I do not understand why they are calling Ising spins to be bosonic. We know the Hamiltonian is for 1D quantum ising model is
\begin{equation}\label{quantIsinghamil}
    {\cal H}_Q=-Jg\sum\limits_{i}\hat{\sigma}_i^x-J\sum\limits_{\langle ij\rangle}\hat{\sigma}_i^z\hat{\sigma}_j^z
\end{equation}

Say, when $g\gg 1$,
$${\cal H}_Q \backsimeq -Jg\sum\limits_{i}\hat{\sigma}_i^x$$
the spins tend to align in direction of field. Here ground state $|\psi_0\rangle = |\rightarrow\rightarrow\rightarrow\dots\rangle$. the quasiparticle excitations corresponds to spin flip in negative $x$ direction, i.e., 
$$|\psi_{i}\rangle=|\dots\rightarrow\rightarrow\underbrace{\leftarrow}_{\textrm{$i^{\textrm{th}}$ spin-flip}}\rightarrow\rightarrow\dots\rangle$$
But still I could not understand how spins are bosonic?

Comment: You should read Section 2.2 in [this book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642330384).

Comment: @YvanVelenik So, raising and lowering operator, they commute at different site so Bosonic. But they anti-commute at same site, so hard core. In short, ising spin are hard core Bosons. Did I get that right?

Comment: Anti-commute at same site: $n^2=n\,\implies n=\pm 1$.

Comment: Yes, that's right.